# Getting temporary error on sudo apt update

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04, sudo

I have recently installed wsl on my windows 10 OS, Ubuntu 18.04 distro.

I tried `sudo apt update` and I am getting temporary error. I have tried everything available on internet but nothing has resolved the error.
[error ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6yf8.png)

My Windows version is `22H2`, and OS build is `19045.2604`
Please help.

I have tried `ping 172.112.31.1`, which was present in nameserver, and I am getting my response back.

I am also connected to internet.

what can be other solution?

Comment: You have a faulty DNS server and it is `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. Can you ping archive.ubuntu.com from windows? Can you ping archive.ubuntu.com inside WSL? Also, are you connected to a university network?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: check the time in wsl using the `date` command